# How to plot gray scale of some data and their confidence interval

Tags: matlab-figure, grayscale, confidence-interval, density-plot

I would like to density plot of some vectors (some realizations in probabilistic concept) and also their confidence interval in Matlab, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6oyE.png)like the figure I attached. The grey shadows are the data and the dashed lines are the confidence interval. Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using Gramm toolbox avaialbale at https://github.com/piermorel/gramm/blob/master/README.md

The link also gives a minimal working example as well as information on more advanced control of the figure.